# How to score 4 of a kind in cribbage after a go

Tags: scoring, cribbage

In Cribbage, we had a go after 3 Aces were played, but then the 4th Ace was played. Does the player receive 12 points for the 4 of a kind or do they receive 6 points for the 3 of a kind before the go and then another 12 for playing the 4th Ace after the go? In other words, how does the go figure in the total count?

Answer (score 2):

No 4-of-a-kind. The Go interrupts the sequence.

From [the rules at Bicycle](https://bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/cribbage/):

> The player who called Go leads for the next series of plays, with the count starting at zero. The lead may not be combined with any cards previously played to form a scoring combination; the Go has interrupted the sequence.

Unless you mean the Go was called before reaching 31 and then the opponent lays the fourth Ace to add to the count before Go to start the next count.

> After gaining the Go, the opponent must first lay down any additional cards he can without exceeding 31. Besides the point for Go, he may then score any additional points that can be made through pairs and runs (described later). If a player reaches exactly 31, he pegs two instead of one for Go.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 4 of a kind, for 12 points (which score is already based on the sequence of pairs). From the rules at https://bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/cribbage/: "After gaining the Go, the opponent must first lay down any additional cards he can without exceeding 31. Besides the point for Go, he may then score any additional points that can be made through pairs and runs (described later)."